# Sorting javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a global array in javascript say
 `jsonArr = ["location","department","grade"];`

now inside my method i am doing this

```
var newArr = [];
newArr = jsonArr;
var sorted_arr = newArr.sort();
```

my newArr is getting sorted but problem is along with jsonArr also got sorted i dont want to sort jsonArr

what is the problem can anyone plz help me ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`newArr` and `jsonArr` are referencing the same array in your code (that's what happens when you simply assign one array to another, like you're doing with this statement: `newArr = jsonArr;`). You need to copy the array first; you can use the [slice method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) for that:

```
var newArr = jsonArr.slice(0);
var sorted_arr = newArr.sort();
```

Answer (score 3):

In line `newArr = jsonArr;` you assing **reference** of `jsonArr` to the `newArr`, which means this two variables will point to the same place in memory (one array). You must copy array explicit before sorting.

```
newArr = [].concat(jsonArr);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var newArr = $.extend(true, [], jsonArr);
var sorted_arr = newArr.sort();
```

You need to make a deep copy. Alternatively you can use the Array.slice() method (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) which actually gives you a better handle.

Hope that helps!!

Comment: Can I ask why the answer was down-voted? The deepcopy - newArr is getting created just fine!

Comment: Hardly acceptable that I don't get an explanation for this! This works for me.